# Joomla error : 500 - JHtml icon not found when adding article to menu item with Artisteer-generated template

Tags: php, joomla

I want to make a new website for a friend. I used Joomla before, with JSNgruve templates. Now I want to create a template with artisteer. It works fine: I have a header image with the webpage-title and a menu bar.

This evening I created the first article for the site. If I add this article to a menu item I get an error:

"500 - JHTML icon not found"

Joomla 3.* is installed on the server, Artisteer 4 is used to design and generate the template files.

I found similar problems to my problem on the internet, and some of them are related to the file html/com_content/article/default.php, but i see different code there than the code that need to be replaced in their problems.

I'm a noob in PHP so don't know where to start...

Comment: Artisteer, please promise you will never use this again. As for the issue, does the template have it's own Template Override for com_content? Check the template folder

Comment: What is a good alternative to Artisteer? Where can I learn (ie a good tutorial?) to make my own templates? Now, I have some knowledge of html/css, but want to learn PHP if necessary...

Comment: Advice #1 - Google is your best friend. There are loads of tutorials out there showing your how to develop a Joomla template. There are also a lot of very good free Templates from top companies such as Yootheme and Rockettheme. Have a look around and see what is to your liking. Personally I hate Artisteer templates as the code that gets generated is just an absolute mess and adapting it can make a beginners life quite hard.